# How can I return a list

Tags: python, list, discord

I wanted to do a discord command scraper in python for the raffles available on https://releases.footshop.com/ and I almost finished it but when I wan to return a list of size (and stock also) it's return an error "IndexError: list index out of range" and I can't find what to do :/

thank for your help guys !

I try this code but it return an error (I try other thing but I don't remember, I had been trying to find a solution by myself for some time now lol)

there is the code:

```
def searchsizefootshop(size):

    item = searchfootshop(size)

    if len(item['sizeSets']['Men']['sizes']) !=0:
        size1 = int(item['sizeSets']['Men']['sizes'][X])
        size = item['sizeSets']['Men']['sizes'][X]['eur']
        count = 0
        while count <= len(size1):
            print(size[count])
            count += 1

searchsizefootshop('hGZrRYMB3xHSyCfZ4BFw')
```

[[scraper](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZG6mS.png)]
[[Footshop API](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e56vI.png)]

Answer (score 0):

`len(size1)` returns the length of the list, not the index of the last item. To loop through a list using `len` and index access, you need to compare it to `len(size1) - 1` or just use `count < len(size1)`.